# Uncaught TypeError: Handlebars.compile is not a function

Tags: handlebars.js

Here is my html:

```
<table id="tableUserPaymentTypeRight">
     <col width="50%"/>
     <col width="25%"/>
     <col width="25%"/>
     <script id="rowUserPaymentTypeRight" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
          {{#each Data}}
              <tr>
                 <td>{{FullName}}</td>
                 <td>
                     {{#if Right_Add}}
                          <input type="checkbox" value="{{UserID}}_0" checked/>
                     {{else}}
                          <input type="checkbox" value="{{UserID}}_0"/>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                      {{#if Right_Confirm}}
                          <input type="checkbox" value="{{UserID}}_1" checked/>
                      {{else}}
                          <input type="checkbox" value="{{UserID}}_1"/>
                 </td>
            </tr>
       {{/each}}
</script>
```

And here is my js:

```
var userPaymentTypeRight = $('#rowUserPaymentTypeRight').html();
var userPaymentTypeRightTpl = Handlebars.compile(userPaymentTypeRight);
var context = data;
var html = userPaymentTypeRightTpl(context);
$('#tableUserPaymentTypeRight').html(html);
```

data like this:

```
{
{UserID: 26031, FullName: "Aaron Zubler", Right_Add: null, Right_Confirm:null, RowIndex: 1},
{UserID: 26390, FullName: "Achilleas Hoppas", Right_Add: null, Right_Confirm: null, RowIndex: 2},
{UserID: 26168, FullName: "Ai Ke", Right_Add: null, Right_Confirm: null, RowIndex: 3},
{UserID: 26310, FullName: "Alessandra Giordanella", Right_Add: null, Right_Confirm: null, RowIndex: 4}
}
```

It seems right according to the API,but I just got the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Handlebars.compile is not a function.

Comment: is Handlebars defined?  What about Handlebars.compile?  I have the exact same code as you do, but I use requirejs to load it.  Perhaps the sample code you were looking at was also loading it via a module loader such as requirejs?  I'd look into the include/load/script inclusion mechanism first myself.

Comment: I also used requirejs to load it,

Comment: what does your **define** look like?  This was mine **define(['bootstrap','jquery',"handlebars"], function(bootstrap, $, Handlebars){**.  Does the firefox/chrome dev tools Net tab show that the GET for handlebars worked?

Comment: yeah,its defined properly,and the get request for handlebars worked.

Comment: I think you should post the requirejs define you used with your code.  Your use of the API itself looks identical to mine.

Comment: require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'handlebars'], function ($, _, Handlebars) {}

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the error happened because I was using the runtime version of the Handlebars. Since I don't intend to precompile my templates (which is not recommended) I've moved to the normal version.

The answer provided by @JL Peyret helped me found out the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
console.log(Handlebars.compile)
```

show?

Done on the Firefox Firebug console, mine shows:

```
function(input, options)
```

And console.dir of Handlebars?  Mine:

```
console.dir(Handlebars)
```

output:

```
helpers   Object { helperMissing=function(),  blockHelperMissing=function(),  each=function(),  more...}
```

....

```
VERSION     "1.3.0"
```

....

```
compile  function(input, options)
```

Comment: it's undefined.maybe there is problem in getting request for handlebars.js.

Comment: Exception: Exception(message, node)
HandlebarsEnvironment: HandlebarsEnvironment(helpers, partials)
REVISION_CHANGES: Object
SafeString: SafeString(string)
Utils: Object
VERSION: "2.0.0"
VM: Object
create: ()
createFrame: (object)
default: HandlebarsEnvironment
escapeExpression: escapeExpression(string)
helpers: Object
log: (level, message)
logger: Object
partials: Object
template: (spec)

Comment: its strange that there is no complie function in this version.

Comment: yeah, my version is 1.3.0.  But even on http://handlebarsjs.com/ they still talk about compile.  My recommendation is post the details of the **define** in your code sample, not just the comments and also specify which version/where you got handlebars.  I am not too too javascript savvy, maybe someone more clever can help.  But there seems more something wrong with your loaded handlebars itself rather than the way you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `handlebars.amd.js` instead.

If you have node, go to temp folder type

`npm install --save handlebars`

go into `\node_modules\handlebars\dist\`

copy file `handlebars.amd.js` into your project.